# run minitest programmatically

Tags: ruby, minitest, pry

I've got this code (in pry):

```
class Hash
  def invert_by_array
    each.with_object({}) {|(key,value), obj|
      value.each do |element|
        obj[element] = key
      end
    }
  end
end

require 'minitest/spec'

describe "invert_by_array" do
  it "should use the array element as keys" do
    {'foo' => %w(bar baz)}.invert_by_array.must_equal({'bar' => 'foo', 'baz' => 'foo'})
  end
end
```

How can I run the test at the bottom from edit - basically copy/paste the content above to the readline?

Comment: side note: `Hash[flat_map { |k, vs| vs.product([k]) }]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the runner by calling `MiniTest::Unit.runner.run`

```
class Hash
  def invert_by_array
    each.with_object({}) {|(key,value), obj|
      value.each do |element|
        obj[element] = key
      end
    }
  end
end

require 'minitest/spec'

describe "invert_by_array" do
  it "should use the array element as keys" do
    {'foo' => %w(bar baz)}.invert_by_array.must_equal({'bar' => 'foo', 'baz' => 'foo'})
  end
end

MiniTest::Unit.runner.run
```

Comment: After two edits, you have two tests. Not really what I wanted. Can I run the object returned by `describe` directly?

Comment: Now days, instead of requiring 'minitest/spec', and ending with `MiniTest::Unit.runner.run`, I'd require 'minitest/autorun' and remove the last line. The test will run automatically just before Ruby exits the script.